# Recursiv function always returns undefined, even if it isn't

Tags: javascript

## Example tree this.props.rodexMatrixData

```
{
"id": "41_0",
"staffNumber": "800001",
"firstName": "adsadsad",
"lastName": "adssadsad",
"role": "CEO",
"phoneNumber": "+4453544534",
"salary": 25000,
"children": [
    {
        "id": "42_0",
        "staffNumber": "800010",
        "firstName": "sda",
        "lastName": "asaas",
        "role": "CTO",
        "phoneNumber": "+44874331234",
        "salary": 20000,
        "email": "ad.ads@aas.dssae"
    }
    ]
}
```

## Code

```
incForFakeLevel(fakeLevel) {
    return ++fakeLevel;
}

mapHierarchy(){
    let mappedHierarchy = [];
    let hierarchyData = this.getHierarchyData(this.props.rodexMatrixData)  //always undefined

    if ( hierarchyData ){
        for (let person of hierarchyData){
            let margin = 10 * person.level;
            mappedHierarchy.push(<div style={{marginLeft: `${margin}px`}}>{person.name}</div>)
        }
    }

    return mappedHierarchy
}

getHierarchyData(tree, hierarchy = [], fakeLevel = 1){
    if (!this.props.selectedPerson)
        return [];

    hierarchy.push({
        name: `${tree.firstName} ${tree.lastName}`,
        level: fakeLevel
    });

    if (tree.staffNumber === this.props.selectedPerson.staffNumber){
        return hierarchy;  // never undefined
    }


    if (tree.children){
        tree.children.forEach( child =>
            this.getHierarchyData(child,hierarchy.slice(), this.incForFakeLevel(fakeLevel))
        );
    }
}
```

*getHierarchyData()* always returns undefined. But if you console.log *hierarchy* in *getHierarchyData()*, its never undefined. *getHierarchyData()* ist supposed to return an array of data.

Whats wrong?

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Have a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If `getHierarchyData` doesn't find the person being searched for in the root of the tree, it falls out the bottom of the function and returns `undefined`. If it finds the person in the root of the tree it does **not** return `undefined`. Notice `hierarchy` is copied using `slice` when calling `getHierarchyData(child,hierarchy.slice()...` (why?) and that the return value of the call is discarded: there is no code to report finding a person in a child node of the tree.

What seems to be missing is a "found" flag to both stop further recursion and also identify tree branches where the person was **not** found which should not be included in the hierarchy. Implementing the found flag can be done in various ways but is simply a property of the `hierarchy` array in the code below.

A possible structure for `getHierarchyData` that returns after finding a person and pops entries off `hierarchy` for false branches,

```
function getHierarchyData(tree, hierarchy = [], level = 1){
    if (!selectedPerson)
        return [];

    hierarchy.push({
        name: `${tree.firstName} ${tree.lastName}`,
        level: level
    });

    if (tree.staffNumber === selectedPerson.staffNumber){
        hierarchy.personFound = true;
        return hierarchy;  // never undefined
    }

    if (tree.children){
        for( let i = 0; i < tree.children.length; ++i) {
            getHierarchyData( tree.children[i], hierarchy, level+1);
            if( hierarchy.personFound) {
                return hierarchy;
            }
        }
    }
    hierarchy.pop();
    return hierarchy;
}
```

References to the object structure of the application have not been included and checking if a person has duplicate records in the tree needs separate verification.

Comment: I need `hierarchy.slice()` to hold the data but destroy the reference at the same time. The hirarchy is like a history, i need to store alle the nodes until i find my node, which i was searching for. When i find the node, i simply return the history/path to the node. So i don't the person, i want the path to him.
** it falls out the bottom of the function and returns undefined** but it gets into the if, when the node is reached. Afterwards it just returns and ends the recursion.

Comment: Return from a  recursive function resumes execution at the point immediately following it's call. If this is within `if(tree.children)` branch of a previous invocation of `getHierarchyData`, that (previous) invocation returns `undefined`. You may wish to try the answer to see what it does.

Comment: Now it return data, but it lost the function i wanted. Without the slice, i don't get the right data.

Comment: [what i mean in a screenshot](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/170103/6xvqaq3n.png) . The green one is the selectedPerson

Answer (score 0):

Solved bei creating a class variable `this.data` . Then just :

```
if (tree.staffNumber === this.props.selectedPerson.staffNumber) {
    this.data= hierarchy;
}
```